# Is there a specific file extension type to save MongoDB queries equivalent to sql file extensions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, phpstorm, webstorm, datagrip

Apologies if the title does not make sense, not too sure what's the best word to put it in just few words and hopefully this is also a good place to ask such question.

Anyways, I am currently using PhpStorm as IDE and connecting with `mongodb`.
But first of all, let me give example in SQL instead.
If I am using PhpStorm and connected to `PostgreSQL`, I can create a file named `query.sql` which has the `sql` file extension, then save whatever `SQL` query I want in there for example

```sql
-- I can also run this query directly from the file
select * from users;
```

So here comes my question, since I am connecting to MongoDB, if I open the query console I can do such to make queries

```js
db.users.find()
```

BUT I am not able to save the query.  If I try to save it'll be under `sql` extension and if I open the `sql` file, I cannot run the query directly from the file.

Wonder if there's a specific file type I should change it into to make it work?
Or maybe there's just no way to run the query directly from file?
If I am asking this in the wrong place please let me know and if there's a better place to ask about this topic please let me know.

Thank you so much for your attention, time and advices.

P.S. I tried changing to `.bson` / `.bjson` extension but none of those works.

Comment: In the mongosh shell you can load `.js` files using `load("filename.js")`, not sure if that will work with what your are using

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file 'something.js' and keep it as a js script like below and execute from mongo cli or mongosh.

File: something.js

```
printjson(db.getCollection('users').find().toArray())
```

Execute something.js like below:

```
mongo mongodb://localhost/yourDb --quiet something.js
```

if you are looking to avoid mongo shell details use --quiet option as well. Also you can output the results to another file as well.

```
mongo mongodb://localhost/yourDb --quiet something.js > out.json
```

For further reading to write scripts, refer the below [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/write-scripts/#:%7E:text=Example%201%20Create%20a%20file%20named%20connect-and-insert.js%20with,and%20query%20the%20movies%20collection.%20use%20myDatabase%20).

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB in DataGrip one needs to save file with `*.js` extension. After that one can run queries via *"Run filename.js"* from context menu or via *Run configuration*

[image]